Jetty Server 9: java.net.UnknownHostException in offline mode

In Eclipse IDE, I try to run basic web application in Jetty Server 9 in the offline mode.
Note: I installed Jetty Server from marketplace in the Eclipse IDE.
I have mentioned the eclipse IDE version and Jetty server version and its configurations

Eclipse IDE Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0) and Build id: 20240606-1231

Error log
    ____    ___                   __    __  __         ___
      / __/___/ (_)__  ___ ___   __ / /__ / /_/ /___ __  / _ \
     / _// __/ / / _ \(_-</ -_) / // / -_) __/ __/ // /  \_, /
    /___/\__/_/_/ .__/___/\__/  \___/\__/\__/\__/\_, /  /___/
               /_/                              /___/

   2024-08-31 06:16:58.209:INFO::main: Logging initialized @375ms to  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
       Configuration: > C:\Users\GOVIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\eclipseJettyPlugin.config.WebTest.xml
             Version: 9.4.49.v20220914
             Context: /WebTest
                Port: 8080
           Classpath: C:/Users/GOVIND KNT/eclipse_jetty/WebTest/build/classes
    2024-08-31 06:16:58.708:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.49.v20220914; built: 2022-09-14T01:07:36.601Z; git: 4231a3b2e4cb8548a412a789936d640a97b1aa0a; jvm 22.0.2+9
    2024-08-31 06:16:59.115:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@13b6aecc{/WebTest,file:///C:/Users/GOVIND%20KNT/eclipse_jetty/WebTest/src/main/webapp/,STOPPED}{C:\Users\GOVIND KNT\eclipse_jetty\WebTest\src\main\webapp}
    java.net.UnknownHostException: www.eclipse.org
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:752)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:377)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1243)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1129)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1691)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:223)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:691)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1443)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1409)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:257)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1182)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1070)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:973)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:635)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:113)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:551)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:890)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:826)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:134)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1225)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:326)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setDefaults(MetaData.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9Adapter.start(Jetty9Adapter.java:68)
        at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.common.AbstractJettyLauncherMain.launch(AbstractJettyLauncherMain.java:84)
        at net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain.main(Jetty9LauncherMain.java:42)
    2024-08-31 06:16:59.164:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1d9b7cce{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
    2024-08-31 06:16:59.164:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1360ms
    -----------------------------------------------
    Jetty startup finished in 1.2 s.
    Used memory: 6.0 MB of 20.0 MB (3.9 GB maximum)
    Console available: type "help".
    -----------------------------------------------


I have a very basic index.html for my web application:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>


web.xml:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>WebTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


The problem is with web.xml. To be specific with WebTest.xml

Please post your web.xml or WebTest.xml

Hi, i mentioned  web.xml

Thanks. I saw. Can you provide the WebTest.xml

I didn't mention webText.xml in basic project. is it default file?

Can you search for this keyword "www.eclipse.org" in the whole project? Tell me where it's used.

i searched but it shows 0 matches

Ok. Got it. Let me check.

Jetty 9 is EOL (End of Life), it is no longer supported..
You seem to want to use Java 22, for that you are required to use Jetty 12 or newer, as there are many changes to the JVM that are breaking your usage of Jetty. (in your case, it's XML dtd validation changes).
Note: You can use javax.servlet on Jetty 12 with the ee8 environment.
